# PowerShell script runs once

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Powershell version 3
I write function in file ONE.ps1:

```
Function ONE {
Write-Output "test1";
}
```

Then I create file !RUN.ps1 in the same directory with content:

```
import-module D:\ps\ONE.ps1
ONE
```

After I run PS console, I could execute this code just 1 time:

> .\!RUN.ps1

Output: test1

But when I try to do it second time, i got an error:

> ONE : The term 'ONE' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

After restarting console I have, again, one successful execution and then errors.

So, could you suggest what is going wrong?

Additional details: just after I create this scripts I could execute it few times, but in a few days, probably after reboot, this error appears. So maybe I'm missing some import-directives that was made while I write it first time, but forgot to add to the final script.

Answer from Martin Brandl solve the problem:

> import-module D:\ps\ONE.ps1 -force

But if somebody know another ways - it would be interesting to check them out. Because module already should be registered. And Get-Module command can see this module, but for some reason I can't use it, that kinda not right.

Comment: you could try to use the `-force` parameter on the `Import-Module` cmdlet.

Comment: thanks, this helps.

Comment: You are welcome. I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-force` parameter on the `Import-Module`.